# Securing WordPress running on Azure platform

Tags: security, cloud

We have a static website hosted on Microsoft Azure. Our marketing team wanted a easy way to update it so WordPress was installed on Azure, the site was created, marketing team updates it. A WordPress plug-in exports their updates as HTML which is shown on the static website. By not allowing WordPress to constantly run, it reduces our risk of WordPress vulnerabilities.

1. Can using plug-ins like WordFence, iThemes security help for a case like this?
2. How can I ensure when newer versions of WordPress is released, it is updated automatically?
3. Any other advice would be appreciated.

I have gone through
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/azureossds/best-practices-for-wordpress-security-on-azure

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

Comment: So to be clear, is the HTML that's being exported a complete copy of the website placed in a separate web server instance? ie. the static website and WordPress website are entirely separate?

Comment: The WordPress installation is on the same Azure instance and installed as an app. The marketing team turns on the WordPress app, makes changes, exports the HTML, then turns off the WordPress app. The exported HTML is in a storage account in the same Azure instance and displayed to our customers, partners on the Internet etc.

Comment: Ok. And when the WP app is on, is WordPress accessible to the internet or is it restricted to internal visitors by e.g. VPN, VDI, Firewall etc?

Comment: I think its going to be tough to answer this one - I certainly can but its more of a conversation or consultation. Re Q2, which is definitely a clearer question, there are plenty of articles online to help you with this but the key point is that the server will need to be on for any auto updates to happen... which means that unless you are automatically switching the app on or off, they aren't really 'auto updates'?